# I need help writing a python program that checks to see if the last character in a list repeats

Tags: python

I've written a program similar that checked if the first letter occurred again, however how do you access the last character in a list when it could be any length? This program runs through the list and if the last character occurs more than once, return true, otherwise return false.

My program for the first repeat looked like this:

def first_letter_repeats(string):

```
 return string[0] in string[1:]
```

def as_yes_no(string):

```
bool_ = string[0] in string[1:]

return ['no', 'yes'][bool_]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python can access the last element of a list by using:

someList[-1]

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try!